# How to automatically generate polynomial with roots known

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

For example I give wolfram alpha the equations $a^2=b, b^2 = c, c^2 = a$ to solve, and I get the following as answers.
[image: what wolfram alpha gave me]

However, I want $a,b,c$ to be the three roots of a degree $3$ polynomial, is there anyway to utilize the process so I don't have to type each set of solutions in manually?

(This is my first time asking a question, hopefully I have made myself clear)

Comment: Not clear, how are you going to get the 7-root from a 3rd degree polynomial?

Comment: If `a`, `b`, and `c` are the roots of the polynomial then the polynomial is just 

`Times @@ (x - {a, b, c})`

Answer (score 3):

This site is about Mathematica and the Wolfram language, not WolframAlpha.

```
eqns = {a^2 == c, b^2 == a, c^2 == b};
```

The solutions are

```
solns = Solve[eqns, {a, b, c}]
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions

```
(And @@ eqns) /. solns

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

The polynomials (with duplicates removed)

```
(polys = Times @@ (x - {a, b, c}) /. solns // 
    DeleteDuplicates) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

For alternate representations

```
polys // Expand // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The real solutions are

```
solnsR = Solve[eqns, {a, b, c}, Reals]

(* {{a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0}, {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}} *)

(polysR = Times @@ (x - {a, b, c}) /. solnsR) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is doable in a much more compact way than the previous answer:

```
Collect[x^3 + C[2] x^2 + C[1] x + C[0] /. 
        SolveAlways[{x^3 + C[2] x^2 + C[1] x + C[0] == (x - a) (x - b) (x - c),
                     a^2 == b, b^2 == c, c^2 == a}, x], x, FullSimplify] // Union
   {x^3, -1 + 3 x - 3 x^2 + x^3,
    -1 - 1/2 I (-I + Sqrt[7]) x + 1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[7]) x^2 + x^3,
    -1 + 1/2 I (I + Sqrt[7]) x + 1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[7]) x^2 + x^3}
```

and to pick out real solutions,

```
Select[%, VectorQ[Im[CoefficientList[#, x]], PossibleZeroQ] &] // Factor
   {x^3, (-1 + x)^3}
```